# Bash: Search Contents of File A in File B and Print lines of File A in File C

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have two files A and B
File A:

```
976464
792992
```

File B

```
TimeStamp,Record1,976464,8383,ABCD
```

I want to search each record in file A and File B and print the records that match.
The Records Printed must be from File B

For example, above should print:

```
TimeStamp,Record1,976464,8383,ABCD
```

I want to achieve this in shell scripting. The File Size is huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `awk` here. Simple `grep` does the job:

```
grep -Ff file1 file2
Timestamp,Record1,976464,8383,ABCD
```